# C# Regular expression for id card number?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to construct a regular expression which is of the format "xxxxx-xxxxxxx-x" where x are all numbers...Help?

EDIT:

I have this so far:

```
string pattern = @"\d{5}[-]"
```

Comment: Do you want to show us an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) ([Give a man a regular expression...](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/give-a-man-a-fish.html))

Comment: @2pietjuh2 Made an edit...

Comment: Something like `^\d{5}-\d{7}-\d$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex.Match(input, @"\b\d{5}-\d{7}-\d$");
```

Comment: This also matches 00000-0000000-0000000000. Shouldn't that be `@"^\d{5}-\d{7}-\d$"`?

Answer (score 2):

that regex would look like this:

```
string pattern = @"\b\d{5}-\d{7}-\d";
```

also checkout this tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: you mean 7 instead of 8? as I want 7 digits here?

Answer (score 1):

```
string strRegex = @"[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{7}\-[0-9]{1}";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"12345-1234567-9";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```